# Prove $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $p$ be an integer with this property: whenever $b, c \in \mathbb Z$ such that $p\mid bc$, then $p\mid b$ or $p \mid c.$ Prove $p$ is prime. Here is my attempt at a proof:

Suppose $d \mid p$. Then $p = dt$. So, $p \mid dt$, implying $p \mid d$ or $p \mid t$.

Suppose $p \mid d$. Since $d \mid p $, then $d = \pm p.$

Suppose $p \mid t$. Since $p \mid dt$, then $pj = dt$. But we know $p \mid t$, so $d$ must be $\pm 1.$

Are you convinced?

Comment: What is your definition of primeness? For me, it is the condition you have to show.

Comment: You need to assume that $p\ne \pm 1$ in the first sentence.

Comment: @  user218931, an integer $p \neq 0, \pm 1$ is prime if the only divisors of $p$ are $\pm 1$ and $\pm p$.

Comment: This is called Euclid's lemma. This is already answered on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last argument does not prove anything. The equation $pj=dt$ is possible with $j=1$ and does not imply that $d=\pm 1$.

What you need is this : since $p \, | \, t$, $t = pj$ for some $j$, hence $p = dt = pdj$, so that $dj = 1$. The solutions to this equation in $\mathbb Z$ are $d=j=1$ or $d=j=-1$, so now you are done.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Does the first part look ok to you?

Comment: @Scheme : Yes, the last part is the only part that was incorrect, that's why I commented only about it. The rest is fine!

Comment: @ Patrick Da Silva, Nice :)

Answer (score 2):

Assume, $p=ab$ with $1<a,b<p$. Then, $p$ divides neither $a$ nor $b$, but $ab$.

If $p=-ab$ with $1<a,b<-p$, then $p$ divides neither $-a$ nor $b$, but $-ab$.

Comment: What about $p=-13$?

Comment: Negative numbers for which the absolute value is prime, are usually considered to be prime also.

Comment: Yes. This was somehow my point, though phrased very poorly. You cannot write $p=-10$ as $ab$ with $1 < a,b < p$ though it is not prime. More to the point, your argument does not account for negative numbers.

Comment: If you have $p=-10$, p does neither divide $2$ nor $-5$, but it divides $-10$.

Comment: Well, sure. But your argument only allows positive $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I assumed $p$ to be positive, but it is easy to extend the result to the integers.